# How can I run a command from the directory I've cd'd into

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to loop through some directories and run a command from within each. The cd seems to work (when I check with echo $dir), but myScript.py gets executed from the parent directory (as if cd didn't work).

```
for dir in $DIR_PROJECTS
 do
   cd $dir && /scripts/myScript.py -f $dir.xml
done
```

Comment: No, myScript is here: /scripts/myScript.py, but the passed argument ($dir.xml, which exists in each subdirectory) isn't found.

Comment: It's found in the first `$dir`, but not the rest, right? It's because you've done `cd` as I mentioned. Do this: `(cd "$dir" && /scripts/myScript.py -f "$dir.xml")` - that way the `cd` is made in a subshell so that the next iteration can also do `cd` successfully.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem you're asking about but `DIR_PROJECTS` should be an array accessed by `for dir in "${DIR_PROJECTS[@]}"`, not a scalar variable accessed by `for dir in $DIR_PROJECTS`. Does `DIR_PROJECTS` contain absolute paths to your directories or relative paths?

Comment: Any possibility of odd characters like spaces in any of the directory names? You should really be using an array. Try running it with `set -x` active. You could also check for the file - `(cd "$dir" && ls "$dir.xml" && /scripts/myScript.py -f "$dir.xml")`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: You did not show the content of `$DIR_PROJECTS`. Could it be that this variable does **not** contain **absolute** pathes of your project? For debugging, run your code with `set -x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you loop and do `cd $dir` in each iteration of the loop, you need to return to the directory that was the current directory before `cd $dir` after you've run the script, or else the next iteration will try to `cd` from the previous `$dir`, which will most likely fail if you are using relative paths.

The most convenient solution is to run it in a subshell:

```cpp
(cd "$dir" && /scripts/myScript.py -f "$dir.xml")
```

That way, the current shell will never `cd` and the next iteration will have the same current directory as the previous one.

Comment: @tjm3772 As you can see, `cd ..` is mentioned more in the spirit of what needs to be done. The actual suggestion is to run `cd "$dir" && ...` in a subshell so the problem of figuring out if the previous `cd "$dir"` actually succeeded etc. becomes a non-issue.

Comment: @tjm3772 I've updated it and removed the mentioning of `cd ..`. Is this clearer?

Comment: Yes better, thanks for updating.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `for dir in $DIR_PROJECTS`, because if any item contains spaces, they will be split.

As [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) commented:

> [...] `DIR_PROJECTS` should be an array accessed by `for dir in "${DIR_PROJECTS[@]}"`, not a scalar variable [...]

If the items in `DIR_PROJECTS` are not absolute paths, the script will not work, as [@TedLyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) explained.

Changing directories in scripts is troublesome in general,
so it's best to avoid when you can. If `myScript.py` works with paths not limited to the current working directory, then this would work just find, without changing directories:

```
DIR_PROJECTS=(
  "path1"
  "path2"
)

for dir in "${DIR_PROJECTS[@]}"; do
    /scripts/myScript.py -f "$dir.xml"
done
```

(Notice that I enclosed in double-quotes `"$dir.xml"` too, also an important thing to do to protect from whitespace and special characters in `$dir`.)